# How do I match rows within a group and filter the rows that do not agree?

Tags: r

In this example dataset, I have 3 groups with 2 different views and 2 different types. Here is what I want to achieve:

1. Determine whether the two types within a group match (Y or N)
2. If the types do not match, I want to select the row where Type = Y
3. If the types DO match, remove the duplicate so that I end up with a data frame with only one
   entry per group (Type = Y or Type = N)

Here is my example data:

```
structure(list(grp = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"), view = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), type = c("Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I want the resulting dataset to look like this:

```
structure(list(grp = c("1", "2", "3"), view = c("A", "A", "A"
), type = c("Y", "Y", "N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
d1 %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  filter(
    n_distinct(type) == 1 & row_number() == 1 | 
    n_distinct(type) == 2 & type == 'Y'
  ) %>% ungroup()
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  grp   view  type 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     A     Y    
2 2     A     Y    
3 3     A     N
```

Read as, within each group, keep the rows that satisfy either of these criteria:

- There is one type in this group, and this row is the first row (this is arbitrary, you didn't specify which row to keep in this case)
- There are two types in this group, and this row has type Y

Comment: +1, the OP probably should `ungroup()` the output or use `.by` argument in `filter` if they are using dplyr > 1.1.0.

Comment: Yes you're right, though I'm not keen to use `.by` since it is still experimental.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you very much! I knew how to group and ungroup but I couldn't figure out how to filter in a way that made sense, I learned some cool new syntax from this, thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way with `ave`. First create a logical index equal to `TRUE` when the conditions are met, then subset the data.frame.

```r
df1 <- structure(list(
  grp = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"), 
  view = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), 
  type = c("Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

i <- with(df1, ave(type, grp, FUN = \(x) {
  if(x[1] == x[2]) {
    c(TRUE, FALSE)
  } else x == "Y"
})) |> as.logical()
df1[i, ]
#>   grp view type
#> 1   1    A    Y
#> 3   2    A    Y
#> 5   3    A    N
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>